# $scope not getting defined properly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to attach `notes` to `$scope` instead of controller(this) in the following code:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.controller('NotesIndexController', ['$http', function($http) {
  var controller = this;


  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'}).success(function(data) {
    controller.notes = data;
  });
}]);
```

So, when I define `$scope` like the following :

`.controller('NotesIndexController', ['$scope', function($scope)`

It doesn't work as I would need to define `$http` somewhere in order to use it in the code? So, where exactly I should define `$scope` then?

I have referred [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 angular
    .module('NoteWrangler')
    .controller('NotesIndexController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)  {

       $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'}).success(function(data) {
          $scope.notes = data;
       });

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't "define" `$scope`, it is a framework object that is managed for you.

If you use the ControllerAs Syntax, your controller can be added to `$scope` as a property.  Otherwise, you would need to refer to the `$scope` object that is injectable through Angular Dependency Injection.  You can inject as many dependencies as you need for your app.

So, the two options which you have available to you are:

ControllerAs:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.controller('NotesIndexController', ['$http', function($http) {
  var controller = this;


  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'}).success(function(data) {
    controller.notes = data;
  });
}]);

<div ng-controller="NotesIndexController as controller">
    {{controller.notes}}
</div>
```

Direct `$scope`:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler')
.controller('NotesIndexController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  var controller = this;


  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.notes = data;
  });
}]);

<div ng-controller="NotesIndexController">
    {{notes}}
</div>
```

Note that the `$scope` object is implicit in the first example and not required in the controller code, and explicit in the second.  Also note, `$scope` has some specific rules regarding primitives and Prototype Inheritance, so it is always recommended to use a dot in your HTML bindings, which the ControllerAs syntax enforces automatically.

Ultimately, the choice of which syntax to use is up to you, but it's recommended to be consistent throughout your application, and either always reference `$scope` or only reference it for special properties you can't reach any other way.

Comment: Use the Controller As syntax, it's definitely the way to go. $scope has other methods on it and if you use Controller As it makes you inject $scope only when you really need it. That's only one of the many benefits to that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `var controller = this;` but you have not injected $http

You can use it like

```
.controller('NotesIndexController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
   $http({method: 'GET', url: '/notes'})
      .success(function(data) {
       $scope.notes = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: In first version, it was not  there, updated latter on